# "Sequence contains no element" when it actually find one

Tags: c#, linq

I have actually all working around :

- my connection work well
- my table is getted
- my field is founded into my class
- I get my mac address from my item to compare it

But when I continue my debug the LINQ code go into the "catch Exception" part and gave me this error... Why ?

Here the Debug screen shot :
[image: Screen shot : code + debug]

I don't know why the sample doesn't return the error but with bool comparison I get the "No way, I can't compare object with bool" which is more explicit than "Sequence contains no element".

Here the sample (if you have a different way to show the code, please let me now, this is my first Stack overflow post :B ) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Exemple
{
    public class LocalDTB
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyEntity> MyEntityTab = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyEntity>();
    }

    public class InheritedClass
    {
        public long Id { get; protected set; }
    }

    public class MyEntity : InheritedClass
    {
        public string Name;
        public string MacAddress;
        public bool IsIncredible;
        public DateTime LastConnection;

        public MyEntity(long id, string name, string macAddress, bool isIncredible, DateTime lastConnection)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            MacAddress = macAddress;
            IsIncredible = isIncredible;
            LastConnection = lastConnection;
        }

        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyEntity> GetAllLocal() => LocalDTB.MyEntityTab;
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            MyEntity element1 = new MyEntity(10, "ghuilobiukg", "E5:AB:4C:D3:24:68", true, new DateTime());
            MyEntity element2 = new MyEntity(5422, "qsdlkjfhmsssszzzz", "F1:7D:89:3E:AB:87", false, new DateTime());

            ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyEntity> myTab = GetLocalTable<MyEntity>();
            myTab.GetOrAdd(element1.Id.ToString(), element1);
            myTab.GetOrAdd(element2.Id.ToString(), element2);

            Console.Write("Searching element with name : ghuilobiukg\n");
            MyEntity elementFound = GetOneLocal<MyEntity>("Name", "ghuilobiukg");
            if (elementFound != null)
            {
                Console.Write("Element found with name : " + elementFound.Name + "\n");
            }

            Console.Write("Searching element with macAddress : F1:7D:89:3E:AB:87\n");
            elementFound = GetOneLocal<MyEntity>("MacAddress", "F1:7D:89:3E:AB:87");
            if (elementFound != null)
            {
                Console.Write("Element found with name : " + elementFound.Name + "\n");
            }

            Console.Write("Searching element with isIncredible : true\n");
            elementFound = GetOneLocal<MyEntity>("IsIncredible", true);
            if (elementFound != null)
            {
                Console.Write("Element found with isIncredible : " + elementFound.IsIncredible + "\n");
            }
        }

        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, T> GetLocalTable<T>()
        {
            MethodInfo getAllLocal = typeof(T).GetMethod("GetAllLocal");
            if (getAllLocal == null)
            {
                Console.Write("Method GetAllLocal not found into " + typeof(T).Name + "\n");
                return new ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>();
            }
            else
                return (ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>)getAllLocal.Invoke(null, null);
        }

        public static T GetOneLocal<T>(string fieldName, dynamic value)
            where T : InheritedClass
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(T).GetFields(); // Just to see what you can get
            FieldInfo fieldFound = typeof(T).GetField(fieldName);
            if (fieldFound == null)
            {
                Console.Write("field not found into class\n");
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                return (from Item in GetLocalTable<T>()
                        where fieldFound.GetValue(Item.Value) == value
                        select Item.Value).First();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("value not found with code error : " + e.Message + "\n");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are those classes and how are they related to connections and tables? If you were using Enumerables I'd say that the sequence doesn't contain any data even if you think it does. If this was an EF Core query, I'd say the same. If you use some other LINQ provider to translate the LINQ query to SQL, it may be a bug in that provider. Or the data isn't what you think it is

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - that'll make it *much* easier to help you.

Comment: If you connect to a server-based database you can use that database's tools to inspect the actual query that gets executed and run it yourself to see if there's any data returned. In SQL Server you can use the XEvent Profiler

Comment: @JonSkeet You can use the method above to repoduce it, the type pulled from "GetLocalTable<T>" is a ConcurrentDictionary<string, Object> and the Inherited class give access to "uri" and "id" attributes to my generic type (useless here btw).
Answer bellow btw.

Comment: @Matheus_UG: We shouldn't have to start adding extra code in order to reproduce it. Please provide a sample that we can copy, paste, compile and run.

Comment: @JonSkeet You can do it now, please let me know if you need more to reproduce it :)

Comment: That's much better in terms of being complete - it's a very long way from being minimal though. Here's a much simpler version which still demonstrates the problem: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/40d5b5b88fc33281ce4afa43ae52e698

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes for sure haha ! I was trying to be the nearest possible to my original code, but with distance we didn't need that much details :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ok a simple cast into dynamic fix it (-_-')
>
> ```
>  return (from Item in GetLocalTable<T>()
>          where (dynamic)fieldFound.GetValue(Item.Value) == value
>          select Item.Value).First();
> ```

**UPDATE - 18/07/2022**

Solution above work but it's better to go that way :

```
 return (from Item in GetLocalTable<T>()
         where fieldFound.GetValue(Item.Value).Equals(value)
         select Item.Value).First();
```

Comment: Why `dynamic` instead of `object`? Or better yet `string` ? Do you understand what that code does? You tried to compare two different types, which means you tried to use *reference equality*. Had you used `Equals()` there would be no problem, because `String.Equals` would be called. Since the types are actually strings, why not cast to string?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I do, In the screenshot case, a string is compared but this code can compare any type which can exist so you have to globalize this part. Dynamic is a "placeholder" / "Any" type before compilation and represents the current type treated.

Comment: To complete the answer :
If you don't cast you're going to compare object<something> with something, this can work, but in some cases not (like bool in the sample).
So cast it into "dynamic" let know to the code that you want to compare "something with something" through the dynamic type.

Comment: You didn't understand what's going on then. No, a string is not compared in the screenshots. Two objects instances are compared for equality ie, whether they're the same object instance or not. You don't need dynamic to use a type's `Equals`, you need to make `value` generic as well, eg `GetOneLocal<T,TValue>(string fieldName, TValue value)`.

Comment: *Or* you can use `Object.Equals(object)` no matter the type, because all types inherit `Object.Equals` and many override it. `String.Equals(Object)` overrides `Object.Equals(Object)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Equals work and it's cleaner, thanks !
I understand the second generic type definition like :
"you control what you compare instead of letting the dynamic type do it on its own"
Am I right ?